# Best way to attenuate R2R DAC output?

Tags: operational-amplifier, dac, attenuation

Given an N-bit R2R DAC, with input voltages of e.g. 0-3.3 volts, what is the the best way (signal integrity and quality maintained) to attenuate its output voltage to a range e.g. 0-.7 volts for a VGA signal.

Is it as simple as using a voltage divider, or would something like an opamp be more appropriate?

Comment: depends... how much drive strength do you need? what is the load impedance?

Comment: VGA would be 75 ohms, unless someone forgot to terminate it.  Essentially, one either designs the ladder *for* the load impedance, or you need a suitable amplifier (*video amplifier* is a category) with less than unity gain or with an output divider including the load impedance.  Also, given likely AGC it may not matter, as long as electrical maximums are not exceeded.

Comment: @jonRB current draw would never exceed 40 mA, and load impedence would be 75 ohms. For the purpose of making this question/answer more useful for everyone, I would be interested in the answer for high vs low current draws and high vs low load impedances.

Comment: @ChrisStratton even if designing for the load impedance, how would you factor in the specific output voltage? I understand how to design an R2R DAC with a max output equivalent to the input level, but not with a specific lower gain.

Comment: @Answoquest - Conceptually one way you could do it would be to design your DAC with some additional high order bits that you only ever drive as zero - ie, go from 8 to 10 bits and now your maximum is 1/4 of the previous voltage.  Then you could simplify the redundant components into a smaller number.  I believe if you study the result you'll be able to see how you could then use different values to create  a gain fraction which is not a power of two, but I haven't actually done it on the back of an envelope.

Comment: @ChrisStratton interesting solution! Seems a bit... cudgeled though?

Comment: It's a thought process to getting to an end result using the concepts you are already employing - the end result itself would be simpler.  Sometimes a spreadsheet program is good for playing with ideas like this.  Or write a little custom code to chart the possibilities.  Or use a circuit simulator, but those don't tend to be ideal for exploring a multidimensional set of possible changes.

Comment: Seems to me that a raw R2R ladder outputs a current. If you desire an output voltage, you might consider a current-to-voltage converter stage having very low input-impedance. An inverting high-speed op-amp and a feedback resistor comes to mind.

Comment: Emitter follower.

Answer (score 1):

The R-2R ladder has a fixed output impedance of R. If you shunt it with a resistor Rx you can attenuate the output equally for all codes. The output impedance will obviously be R||Rx.

You thus have two degrees of freedom that allow you to set the output impedance and output amplitude independently.

In this case, if you set R = 353 ohms and Rx = 95.2 ohms you will get the desired characteristics (full scale output voltage of 0.7V with 3.3V supply and 75 ohms output Z).

Comment: Could you please clarify R||Rx?

Comment: The parallel combination of R and Rx = R*Rx/(R+Rx)

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! I'm having trouble putting together equations to calculate values for R and Rx...

We know (R*Rx)*(R+Rx) = 75, and 
Vout_max = 3.3*(7/8) = 2.89 V. We need Vout_max = 0.70 V.

We have a system of two unknowns here, so do I just have to trial and error values?

Comment: For clarification, this would be for a 3-bit DAC specifically, but I'm also interested in developing an equation (set) for n-bit DACs.

Comment: You should solve the system of two equations. The number of bits doesn't matter except that you need to adjust it a little if you care about the difference of one LSB.